# Azure - trying to create encrypted storage account

Tags: rest, azure

the storage account encryption is finally live
and I have tried to create an encrypted storage account using REST call
and i am getting an error
my url is

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/dddddd-cccccc/resourceGroups/Encryptedrg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/i2lhqulophtmyu2?api-version=2016-01-01

but I am getting an error which - according to it, Azure thinks I am sending the old request

> Error Message: Code: AccountTypeMissing Message: The accountType field is missing from the request.

Comment: Can you share the request body you're sending to create the storage account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested on my local. Please double check your code with my reply. Here is the result: 
[image]

The Rest API document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163564.aspx

**PUT:**

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription ID}/resourceGroups/jatestgroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/akingtt?api-version=2016-01-01

**Header:**

Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhb......
Content-Type: application/json
Host: management.azure.com
Content-Length: 443

**Request Body**

```html
{
    "location": "East Asia",
    "tags": {

    },
    "properties": {

        "encryption": {
                "services": {
                         "blob": {
                                 "enabled": true
                         }
                },
                "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"    
        }
    },
    "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_RAGRS"
    },   
    "kind": "Storage"
}
```

Please note:
 1) "Kind" is Required in version 2016-01-01 and later. 
2) "accessTier" is Required when kind = 'BlobStorage'.
Forbidden when kind = 'Storage'.
 3) prior to version 2016-01-01, **'sku' was called 'accountType'** and was found under the 'properties' envelope.

Comment: OK, this is a great answer but where on earth is this documented? I've been stumped by this for the last hour and happy to have found a solution but I can't seem to find solid documentation on this, how are we supposed to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I just created an encrypted storage account in the Azure portal.  When I look at the [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com), the URL shows an API version of 2015-05-01-preview.

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/STORAGE_ACCT_NAME?api-version=**2015-05-01-preview**

Comment: what is the body of the request, as in their documentation, in this version, encryption isnt supported